# Why can't it find a table field?

Tags: c#

I'm still pretty new to C# and I'm trying to pull a record from a table. Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Users");
        DataRow[] foundRows;
        string srch = "username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND '" + textBox1.Text + "'";

        try
        {
            foundRows = tbl.Select(srch);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            return;
        }

        string passwrd = foundRows[0][1].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("Password: " + passwrd);
    }
```

Now when It gets to the try command, it throws an exception back and part of the MessageBox says 'Cannot find column [username].'
Now I checked my Users table and the username field is in there with the correct spelling as well as being in all small lettering. So could someone please explain why I'm getting this message? Thanks.

Comment: But you initialize a new instance of `DataTable` with a table called `Users` as an empty.

Answer (score 1):

DataTable.Select() doesn't actually connect to a database a retrieve information, it only reads from the rows inside a DataTable it assumes is already populated. Here is an example that will populate a DataTable, and avoid SQL Injection risks. In this example my application will connect to a database called "MyDatabase", then query the Users table with a filter on the username of "SomeUser". Then it will get the "MyField" field and read it into a string called someValue.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = "SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDatabase";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = @username");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", "Someuser"));
        DataSet dataSet = ExecuteDataset(cmd, connectionString);

        DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
        string someValue = table.Rows[0]["MyField"].ToString();
    }


    public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(SqlCommand cmd, String connectionString)
    {
        // Create the SqlConnection, DataAdapter & DataSet
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            // Fill the DataSet
            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            da.Fill(dataSet);

            // Return the dataset
            return dataSet;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, you have not defined columns for your Users table. If you declare your Users table outside of the provided click event, your are negating it with the instantiation of a new DataTable.

Comment: So should I use a connection string to open the dataset first and then set the DataTable?

Comment: You can open a connection to your data source (assuming a database) and load the data into your Users DataTable.

Comment: I surrounded my code with using(SqlConnection connect = .... ) and I als have a connect.Open() command as the first line within it and I'm still getting that error. What else could I do?

Comment: after you open the connection, do you load the data into the DataTable?

Comment: As you saw in my code I create the datatable and then I use the datatable.select(). Isn't that loading the data?

Comment: No, that is selecting data in a DataTable, you have to fill the DataTable with data first in order to select from it.

Comment: ok thank you. I just have to go back to the books because I'm teaching myself c#. Thanks for your help.